# How to link an html file in the readme.md file and open it

Tags: github, github-pages

I generated the javadoc docs files for one of my school project and I want visualize the html files by a link in the readme file.
The problem is when i link the /docs/index.html it opens the github's "file visualizer" not the html page.
Somebody knows how to link an html page and open directly on the browser?
Thanks in advance